# returns an object or a refrence to object

Tags: android, casting, findviewbyid

Does `findViewById()` and `inflate()` return a view object or "view reference" ?,
asking because we do

```
LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)inflate(R.layout.main,null);
```

So if inflate return view Object ,and view is parent of LinearLayout the how can view's object contains linearLayouts members variables and methods.

Comment: looks like you have missed Java basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
// use this in activity
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llout);

// use this in fragment onViewCreated()
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)View.findViewById(R.id.llout);

// used anywhere in actvity or fragment
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)getView.findViewById(R.id.llout);
```

Comment: do they return a "view obj" itself or a "refrence of type view to an object"

Answer (score 0):

> Does findViewById() and inflate() return a view object or "view reference" ?

It returns a `View` (or subclass) object.

> if inflate return view Object ,and view is parent of LinearLayout the how can view's object contains linearLayouts members variables and methods.

When you inflate a view, *all* of the views in the layout will be inflated, but the returned object will be the top-level view in your layout. Many views (anything that derives from `ViewGroup`) can have "child" views. You can access the children of the returned view by calling `findViewById()` or by accessing them directly with `getChildAt()`.

Let's say we have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stack Overflow"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

We can write code like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

In this case, `view` will be the `LinearLayout` that's the top-level view in our layout. If we want to get the child `TextView`s, we could write this:

```
TextView helloWorld = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextView stackOverflow = ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(1); // index is 0-based
```